# Misma función sobre botones similares (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

Logré codificar la función que necesitaba sobre un botón. Tengo otros 3 botones que cumplen la misma función pero no se le aplicó a pesar de tener la misma clase. Ya intenté con querySelectorAll y no pude resolver. Adjunto código JS

```
    const htmlButton = document.querySelector('.html-button');
const htmlDiploma = document.querySelector('.html-button_span');
const closeDiplomaBtn = document.querySelector('.nav-spanButton_close')


let contador = 0;
 
  

  
function showDiploma() {
    if (contador == 0) {
    htmlDiploma.classList.remove('inactive');
    contador = 1;
    } else {htmlDiploma.classList.add('inactive')};
          contador = 0;
  }

  htmlButton.addEventListener('click', showDiploma, true)


  function hideDiploma() {
    if (contador == 0) {
    htmlDiploma.classList.add('inactive');
    contador = 1;
    } else {htmlDiploma.classList.remove('inactive')};
    contador = 0;
  }

  closeDiplomaBtn.addEventListener('click', hideDiploma, true)
```

Comment: Pero no es muy clara tu pregunta... donde están los "otros 3 botones que cumplen la misma funcion"? Cada botón se relaciona con un `html-button_span`  y un `.nav-spanButton_close` distinto? aclara tu pregunta. Preferiblemente añade tambien la parte relevante del HTML y también explica cual es el comportamiento que esperas tener.

Comment: Estoy trabajando en mi primer portfolio. Al clickear el html-button_span se hace visible un span con una imagen. Al clickear nav-spanButton_ close le da nuevamante el estilo de display:none a ese span con img. Trabaja bien la función, el problema es que tengo otros 3 botones iguales a los cuales no le puedo aplicar dicha funcion. Los botones son iguales, solo cambia la imagen del span que se hace visible. Soy nuevo en el rubro, asi que si necesitas mas especificaciones no tengo problema en pasartelas. Desde ya, gracias

Answer (score 0):

sospecho que el comportamiento no es el esperado porque la sentencia `contador = 0;` está fuera del `else`, por lo que con cada ejecución de ambas funciones el valor final de `contador` siempre será 0, intenta con la siguiente modificación:

```
const htmlButton      = document.querySelector('.html-button');
const htmlDiploma     = document.querySelector('.html-button_span');
const closeDiplomaBtn = document.querySelector('.nav-spanButton_close')

let contador = 0;

function showDiploma() {
  if (contador === 0) {
    htmlDiploma.classList.remove('inactive');
    contador = 1;
  } else {
    contador = 0; // Modificación
    htmlDiploma.classList.add('inactive');
  };
}

function hideDiploma() {
  if (contador === 0) {
    htmlDiploma.classList.add('inactive');
    contador = 1;
  } else {
    htmlDiploma.classList.remove('inactive');
    contador = 0; // Modificación
  };
}

htmlButton.addEventListener('click', showDiploma, true);
closeDiplomaBtn.addEventListener('click', hideDiploma, true);
```

Comment: No es la solución que necesito, sin embargo tu ayuda me hizo prescindir de un boton que habia puesto para cerrar el spam que se hacia visible. Ahorre código y quedó mucho mas estilizado mi portfolio. Gracias!